# GTK Buttons how to create a bevel/3D effect

Tags: css, c, gtk, gtk4

I would like to have my buttons, when toggled, to have a 3D bevelled look, as in the below image, created with Powerpoint:
[image]

Is this possible? In GTK4 the ShadowType and Relief properties [have been removed](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html), and it is recommended to use `gtk_button_set_has_frame()`. I tried this on my button with a CSS image background and it made no difference. Nor does setting the boolean frame value give me any hints as to how to edit and manipulate the frame itself.

Using [css properties](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/css-properties.html) like `box-shadow: inset` or `border-style: groove` I can add a more bevel like feel, but the `transform` property does not appear to have a pressed-in feature as in my above image.